# On selecting TextField (opening keyboard) in ScrollView - content jumps down and back with keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, textfield

My TextField inside of ScrollView, when I select it, all content jumps firstly down, and returns back with keyboard.

```
ScrollView {
  VStack {
     TextField("Placeholder", $value)
     Button()
       .keyboardResponsive(enabled: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you provide demo code?

Comment: please read and consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've found the reason. My screen contains Button with keyboardResponsiveEnabled = true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in property keyboardResponsiveEnabled of one of used on screen button. Parent class of it has keyboardResponsiveEnabled = true by default.
So if you have such problem, check all elements on screen with superclasses for this property.